# how to download video flv video directly from youtube

Tags: javascript, html, flash, youtube

I'm trying to download flv video directly from youtube using

http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=9Mu23wVb--4=TOKEN

Note:In place of TOKEN i placed the value of obtained from below url....

youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id=9Mu23wVb--4

After trying this option, i'm getting page not found. is there any way to get the flv video location from youtube using some tweak's

Note: i know this is against youtube policy but i just wanted to understand how some tools/softwares were able to download youtube video directly

Regards,
Sukumar

Comment: This not really programming related: Voting to migrate to superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Get Firebug and inspect requests/responces when playing video. If you can recreate request(s) with right headers/parameters, you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://keepvid.com/ dun try to download youtube video with this site.

Comment: i tried with that site and it works. Infact i had already tried with firefox youtube plugin and even that worked. just wanted to know how they are extracting flash flv video's from youtube.
It's just for my understanding.....